# Method overloading in PHP is bad practice?

Tags: php, overloading

Trying to achieve [method overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) using PHP (don't confuse with overloading definition from [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)), is not easy there is clear trade off, because of nature of PHP you have to have one method and `if` or `switch` statement inside to provide overloading, it creates procedural code that is difficult to read in long methods.

Is there any advantage of having method overloading in PHP, can it be achieved in any other way?

```
class MyClass {

   public function doMany($input) {

      if (is_array($input)) {
         ...
      } else if (is_float($input)) {
         ...
      }

   }

}
```

versus traditional approach

```
class MyClass {

   public function doArray(array $input) {
      ...
   }

   public function doFloat(float $input) {
      ...
   }

}
```

Comment: This question feels both very broad, and very opinion-based to me. It *might* be more on-topic at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ but read their FAQ carefully first. You will probably get better responses if you can describe a more specific problem you're trying to solve - it's hard to give alternatives that would hold for every possible use of method overloading.

Comment: If you don't want to use a `switch`, then combine use of `gettype()` with dynamically defined method names for individual method calls for each type

Comment: Check this out, it may be relevant to your case: [The Hidden Dangers of Method Overloading](https://www.yegor256.com/2023/08/01/method-overloading.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional approach would be:

```
class Aclass {
  public function doStuff(int $a) {
    // return other stuff
  }

  public function doStuff(float $a) {
    // return other stuff
  }
}
```

Notice the same function name just different **type** for the paramaters.

Your first approach is usually the way to go if you want to simulate overloading in php. Generally speaking you don't really need overloading in PHP since it's loosely type and by definition you can't really have overloading.

---

To answer your question. If you really need to have overloading, then your first approach seems appropriate. Use a switch to make it more readable.

Disclaimer: While you can do that, I don't recommend it. Heck, you can do just about anything if you want to. It doesn't mean you should.

Comment: You can't redclare doStuff. I think you probably didn't mean to imply that the code in the "traditional approach" block would work in PHP, but it would probably be a good idea to specify that it would cause a fatal error.

Comment: That's correct, I didn't intend to mean "traditional approach" in PHP. I mean traditional approach in hard typed languages. And yes, it will throw a fatal.